How to determine refelection symmetry of molecular term in relativistic (spin-orbit) molecular term?
It is quite clear and well-described how to determine the molecular term of diatomic molecule from interacting atoms (including parity and reflection symmetry): https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Quantum_Chemistry_with_Applications_in_Spectroscopy_(Fleming)/09%3A_Molecules/9.05%3A_Diatomic_Term_Symbols
However, the problem is when we want to include spin-orbit coupling (SOC). Let us take as an example ground state oxygen molecule $^3\Sigma_g^-$ . When we include SOC (at second order) this term is split into two terms described by $\Omega=0$ and  $\Omega= \pm 1$. It turns out that the reflection symmetry of "true" is $\Omega=0_g^+$. Thus, reflection symmetry is different from the "non-relativistic" term. How to understand and determine it?
